# If the discrete log is easy in $F_p$ is it also easy in $F_{p^2}$?

Tags: finite-fields, discrete-logarithms

Given a finite field $F_p$, for some large $p$. If DLOG is easy in $F_p$ is it also easy in $F_{p^2}$?

Comment: Can we assume that you have a generator fo $\Bbb F_{p^2}^\times$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes, i think that is a reasonable assumption